# MonoGame 3.4 Content Pipeline Extension missing reference

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm pretty new to MonoGame and XNA in general. So was wondering how I could import custom content and make it work on any platform. So I came across Content Pipeline Extensions wanted to do it like the documentation says but i **cant find MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline**.
So I have multiple questions:

- Where is it located?
- Is there any other way i can load stuff like map data etc.?
- If yes does it work on any platform?

**Edit:**
I can simply load files without the content pipeline. I didn't expect that to work across all platforms. Thanks to Shiro for clearing this up.

Comment: Are you trying to make a game that accepts custom content ? I don't quite understand. If you want to have content (textures, sound, etc) converted to .xnb, there is the [documentation](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/MonoGame-Content-Processing)  you should create a separate project from template `MonoGame Content Project` to convert your content.

Comment: @Shiro I'm trying to load file formats like map files etc. Honestly just being able to load them as a String or Stream would be fine by me. **Edit:** also since MonoGame has it's own Pipeline now Content Projects are no longer necessary .

Comment: What are map files ? Some information saved in a text file ? You don't need monogame to do that, that's already in C# core language.

Comment: @Shiro but will it also work across all platforms?

Comment: Of course it will

Comment: I am pretty sure that .txt files are not even considered as content. Content is textures, fonts, sounds and shaders.

Comment: See my answer below. Textfiles *could* be considered content. Those may include leveldata, character dialogs, anything. It makes sense to pack these in a content file for a couple of reasons. You could pre-process the content, or group content. This makes your content creation (gimp or your own level editor) decoupled from your code. The texture atlas example: I don't have to deal with the atlas but with individual png files. If I change the size of one image, the pipeline rebuilds the atlas at compiletime. It also builds files so your players can't easily change the file- break the game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [MonoGame.Extended](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended) project loads [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) maps using a custom content importer. I wrote a tutorial about how to create custom content importers on [my blog](http://dylanwilson.net/creating-custom-content-importers-for-the-monogame-pipeline).

Of course, as @Shiro mentioned in the comments you don't *need* the Pipeline to load your own content with MonoGame. Just be aware that to make it work across all platforms you'll need to use [`TitleContainer.OpenStream`](http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=M_Microsoft_Xna_Framework_TitleContainer_OpenStream). This is by far the simplest way and if it works for you by all means do it that way.

The idea of using the Pipeline is to give you the opportunity to optimize the content at compile time. You can pre-process the data and write it out as a binary XNB file to be efficiently read into the game. The process is quite involved though:

1. Create a new project to hold your content importer, processor and writer that references the `MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.dll`. It's available as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Portable/).
2. Implement a class that derives from `ContentImporter<T>`
3. Implement a class that derives from `ContentProcessor<T,K>`
4. Implement a class that derives from `ContentTypeWriter<K>`
5. Implement a class that derives from `ContentTypeReader<K>` (in the game project)
6. Reference the DLL from the Pipeline tool (by editing your `Content.mgcb` file)
7. Read the content into your game using `Content.Load<K>`

As you can see custom content importers can be quite daunting at first, but once you've done a few of them they are not too bad. I hope this clears some things up for you.

Finally, to answer your other question.

> Where is it [MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.dll] located?

If you're not using the NuGet package for some reason, the DLL lives with the Pipeline tool in a rather obscure place. On my machine it's located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0\Tools
```

I found it by looking at the path set on the shortcut in the start menu.

Answer (score 3):

the comment made by @Necr0 stating that "content projects are no longer necesary" is not entirely correct. Monogame no longer requires the *XNA content project*. There are still reasons to have your own content pipeline projects. You could, for example, create a content pipeline importer for your own level format. Or, if you plan to support a file format created by a tool you use (Tiled, Spine/Spriter for example). 
I myself made a content project that packs a bunch of images into a texture atlas, so I don't have to deal with that at runtime and I don't need to deal with that in photoshop- just save the individual files and the importer does the rest.

**So, what about those references you were looking for?**

If you want to make your own content projects:
Reference the `MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Portable` package using NuGet. The NuGet package is at the moment (sept 2015) pre-release only package. Make sure you choose `Include Prerelease` at the top of the Manage NuGet Packages window.

[image]

If you're looking to make your own content format. This excellent tutorial helped me a lot by making my own first content project: http://dylanwilson.net/creating-custom-content-importers-for-the-monogame-pipeline

Comment: beat me to it! :P

Comment: :-) by 15 seconds *yeehaw*

Comment: Glad to see my tutorial has been helpful ;) I'd love to know what kind of importers you've been making.

Comment: I started fixing an old XNA importer for Spriter (the animation tool). I ran in a couple of issues and fixed them recreating the importer from scratch using your tutorial. Since then, I made an importer that takes an XML file as input- the XML contains paths where I store my images. The processor creates a texture atlas and writes the image and a dictionary of filenames(key) and struct of texture2D and rectangle(value) to a single contentfile. Works like a charm! Thanks for writing the blog :-)

Comment: You're welcome. The importers sound interesting. I'd love to know more about them. Would you consider posting more info on the [MonoGame.Extended github page](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended/issues)?

Comment: I'll see if I can refactor the spriteatlas content importer so it is generic enough. At the moment it is not in a state to release it 'in the wild' so to speak.

Comment: Don't worry about refactoring yet. The first thing to do is open a discussion about what it does and how it's useful.